# App crash while downloading large images using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImage to download image async from server.Some images on server are of size( 1772x1476 pixels.)I'm showing these images on UICollectionView. I'm getting memory warning and app crashes after several run.Some times it happens when images downloaded first time and some time when i scroll the collection view up and down. Here is my code-

i am getting warning on my x code like below image

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

[Mainimage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: Obj.imageYH] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];

   return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I strongly believe that, this error is not because of image downloading.

Comment: then what is the cause?

Comment: Hi Krish, it's me again. Let's do some calculations. Your 1772 x 1476 px image spent quite a lot of RAM during download. RAM spent is 1772 x 1476 x 24(bit) / 8 = 7846418 bytes = 7662 Kb = 7MB. As the device has limited RAM, you shouldn't load such huge photo to exhaust the memory. Consider to resize the image on server side, or don't load multiple huge photos at the same time. You can confirm the behavior in Xcode memory monitor.

Comment: @Raptor so do i have to inform to server side peoples resize the  images right?

Comment: Yes, or your App will have memory issues. Better, you can use SDWebImage's download manager to download images one by one as well.

Comment: how many pixels of data they have to resize?

Comment: 150X150 pixels ok?

Comment: Hi @Raptor how can we downloads one by one images using SDWEbimage libarry?

Comment: Supply `SDWebImageManager` with multiple image URLs. There's an example in `SDWebImage`'s official GitHub site

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108481/discussion-between-krish-and-raptor).

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

[SDImageCache sharedImageCache].config.shouldDecompressImages = NO;
[[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] setShouldDecompressImages:NO];

In version 4.0-beta

Answer (score 0):

If your app doesn't need to show a full sized image, then it's always a good practice to scale it down and then show. Here's an example of what to do.

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadWithURL:url delegate:self options:0 success:^(UIImage *image) 
{
    //Scale down the image here and then set to your view.
}
```

It should help you reduce the memory issues.

Comment: hello Ruchira Randana u there?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

            UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [Mainimage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: Obj.imageYH] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];

           return cell; 
}
```

Try this

Comment: and it was depricated also

Comment: You can try this also 
[imgView setImageWithURL:[self.imgArray objectAtIndex:index]
                 placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload
                        completed:^(UIImage *image,
                                    NSError *error,
                                    SDImageCacheType cacheType)
         {
             
         } usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];